# Typesafe const assertion map from a subset of keys

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a `const` asserted map based on a **subset** of keys, and when referencing values by index it should be typesafe:

```
type KEYS = 'aa' | 'bb' | 'cc'

// ERROR: property 'cc' is missing in type '{ readonly aa: "foo"; readonly bb: "foo"; }' but required in type '{ aa: string; bb: string; cc: string; }'
const obj: { [k in KEYS]: string } = {
    'aa': 'foo',
    'bb': 'foo'
} as const

// function should be typesafe - calling with `cc` should throw an error
function getValue(key: keyof typeof obj){
    return 
}

getValue('aa') // should be fine, 'aa' key exists
getValue('bb') // should be fine, 'bb' key exists
getValue('cc') // should error out - obj doesn't have 'cc'
```

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA0gogTQMpQLxQOQEMsagH0wCMi9CMBjCjAKDoHp6o4AlFgeRYC4owAnAPaQ+oTFTwBLAM5QAttKkSAdgHMoyqKEiYA3lD4QsAEwFKANiCg4eAIgBmAgTYDc+wyfOWSth09cBfPCIAV2A3AEdgiQMjdSVNcGgMPWsoKWA+ZRVXbzSMrNcqHnTM1QDaClN0qAEiACsePQBtAGs42EQkAF1i-NUofzQoHRooMcwcDB4MXwwAGlHxjBIpzFmaQawZSqV0hiY7YKUKYAlTNIALAWCzWKJoLQgpLDtoAFooCiwzMyyoAHcJMALlAAAZUUGXa63TQXQT-KzxCB8QR8GiHY6nc4qCDAABq32CEAAFC0ICAeGSQAI7AlIDSavUAJQjcZQRhQAB03I2dBx+MJJOwuCZ7KYUiuNzu0DsyggcwmuCgVKgEAAHtJgFIaPyCWYicTlqRRRyJdDpVBZUp5cRSMryaqNeltbrBYbxCbxZKYcjUTVQlAPrU6lATE8lBgwhcsAA3JLiGhAA)

My issue is that the map declaration complains that I'm not using all the keys. If I try typing it as optional, eg:

```
{ [k in KEYS]?: string }
```

then the function `keyof typeof obj` doesn't work correctly since the keys can be optional.

Is there a more elegant way (or is it even possible?) to type the object `as const` with a subset of keys and still achieve typesafety when calling `getValue` with only a **valid** key that was used to initialize `obj`?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to just write `const obj = { ... } as const` without the weaker type annotation?

Comment: Mainly to ensure that the keys as the index signature are from a specific type, and also so `getValue` can eventually be called with that type.

Comment: Your `getValue` function is defined in terms of `typeof obj` so the type of `obj` must include only the keys it actually has. Other than that, you just want a compile-time check that its properties are assignable to the type `KEYS`, correct?

Comment: Yeah, basically - obj should use a subset of the keys, and getValue should effectively only allow that subset of keys as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to have the properties checked at compile-time while retaining the exact type by using a generic identity function, although this has a small cost at runtime:

```
function check<K extends KEYS>(v: Record<K, string>): Record<K, string> {
    return v;
}

const obj = check({
    'aa': 'foo',
    'bb': 'foo'
})
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA0gogTQMpQLxQOQEMsagH0wCMi9CMBjCjAKBoDMBXAOwuAEsB7ZqCgCwgUA1gB4YUCAA9gEZgBMAzrERIAfAAoAbgC4oAJUGcATnLEAaKAuBH2zAOaqAlLoMVjpmBas37qqAG8aKGCoIwhgRiMeTQBuGgBfOjdmKyhOIgArNF4BYXVAkMwcDF0Mek5ODDMgkIwSEsxyyoTHOiZWDm4oO3CANSwAG0YIdSEIEF0xkE56KFBIGbTMxwKQgHo1qAA6HYS6HuB+oZHsXEcoDcs+TkYBuSgiaHpbCAtTvCmJSXYrBRoDo7DdR1UjnS4Ka63e6PKDPZivYikKCfKQ-YB-AGDIGUahgzYQm53CRGIzGNKMYBQAC0Syyck4EAUzAwlL4WE00BxtCAA)