# Typescript object force type for key and infer value type

Tags: typescript

I have an object `obj` which:

- accept keys from `enum ObjKeys`
- accept values which have complex types

Example:

```js
type ComplexType1 = Record<string, number>
type ComplexType2 = Record<string, string>
let value1 : ComplexType1 = { a: 0 }
let value2 : ComplexType2 = { b: '' }

enum ObjKeys {
    Key1 = 'Key1',
    Key2 = 'Key2',
    Key3 = 'Key3',
}

const obj = {
    [ObjKeys.Key1]: value1,
    [ObjKeys.Key2]: value2,
    [ObjKeys.Key3]: value1,
}
```

Typescript compiled my `obj` type perfectly (they know which key has which value's type):

```js
declare const obj: {
    Key1: ComplexType1;
    Key2: ComplexType2;
    Key3: ComplexType1;
};
```

Now the problem is I wanna to strict `obj`'s keys, but still wanna it's value type is infer automatically. Below are my try:

- `const obj: { [key in ObjKeys]: infer} = {` => of couse this is not working
- `const obj: { [key in ObjKeys]: ComplexType1 | ComplexType2 } = {` => it cant infer value automatically, value's type is now `ComplexType1 | ComplexType2`, not correctly which is which

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why do you need that? You can simply use `typeof obj` to get all the inferred types.

Comment: Can you provide typescript playground for your solution? I cant get it. Tried [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gWzAGwgDwCrggRigXigCUIBjOAJwBMAeAZ2AoEsA7AcwBooWBXBAIwgUAfAFgAUKEixEKdFkgAmAsTKVaDZuy6bWbMeNTAoANwCGyHrigAuGUlSZseQgG8oZuwAYoAXwlGphZWynbwDvLYym5Q-HYA5PF+EhIQvAhQAPL8AFYA0hAgdFCuElDlUAUgLlDxVTjxHGUVVdG1rY3N5VUAzCp1hT2d4v7iEuQsDFBwuSql4hVQANrZ+YV0AHT1ALp25pa4TQsVK7lVm627QQeKR4una0Vbg1f7VjhHo+Nwk8YAjn8VFIIHAAGbTXJAA)

Comment: It's still not clear what you're trying to achieve. Your `obj` is already strictly typed. Can you show us an example use case, or at least clarify what you meant by "I wanna to strict obj's keys, but still wanna it's value type is infer automatically"?

Comment: no it is not :D like example, I gonna add some new field to `ObjKeys`, like `Key4`. The `obj` is not error alert about it is missing that new field.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65963971/12299000) answer your question?

Comment: This usecase came from working with a team, I wanna other team member remember to add `obj` whenever they add `ObjKeys`

Comment: taking a look @kaya3

Comment: As I understand right, above problem author wanna to subset key from exist enum, which is different from my problem is trying to infer value type while still trying to strict key type.